# Prove that there is no largest rational number $q$ such that $q^3 < 2$

Tags: number-theory

I know how to prove such things where $q < 2$, but $q^3 < 2$ seems a bit tricky for me. Could someone give me a lead please?

Comment: Assume $0<q$ and $q^3<2$ and consider $p=q+h$ where $h>0$. You have show that we can find $h$ such that $p^3<2$.

Comment: For one such $q$, consider $(q+h)^3=q^3+3q^2h+3qh^2+h^3$ with $h$ small. Can $h>0$ be small enough that $(q+h)^3<2$ still?

Comment: This is what needs to be proved. To simplify calculations note that $r=2-q^3>0$. And then $2-p^3=r-h(3q^2+3qh+h^2)$.

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on? You can't say that you have no ideas; you have an entire textbook, examples, earlier materials in the course, etc.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Isn't that already the answer if you are allowed to use that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Sudix: No one is talking of $\mathbb {R} $. All the numbers and operations are in $\mathbb{Q} $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expand on my comment. Let $q>0$ be rational such that $q^3<2$ so that $r=2-q^3>0$. Let $h>0$ be rational and $p=q+h$ and consider $$2-p^3=r-h(3q^2+3qh+h^2)$$ Let $h<1$ so that $$3q^2+3qh+h^2<3q^2+3q+1$$ and if we take $h<r/(3q^2+3q+1)$ ie $h<\min(1,r/(3q^2+3q+1))$ then we can see that $$h(3h^2+3qh+h^2)<r$$ and hence $2-p^3>0$. Thus the proof is complete. The argument works in exactly the same manner if the exponent $3$ is replaced by any positive integer, for example $100$.

The fundamental idea here is the fact that there is no end to supply of small positive rationals. Given any positive rational, there is a smaller one. This fact studied when learning fractions and their manipulation is the key aspect behind the proofs in calculus and strangely it is never emphasized in entire high school curriculum.

Comment: Alright, thank you! I was pretty confused by the proof at first but I think I've digested it. This proof is quite different from simpler proofs like prove there is no greatest rational less than 2, where you can just take the average of 2 and whatever rational.

Comment: I mean the reasoning is essentially the same, but the complexity is quite different.

Comment: @IUissopretty: it is different or perhaps slight more complicated than that, but based on the same principle. The fact that average lies in between is key to proving that given a positive $q$ there is smaller one. One can just take average of $0$ and $q$.